# Problems creating a query to show sub totals with a specific sub query join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query to list counts for all (US) states in series of joins, so that it shows 0's for all states defined in a table that does not appear in the rest of the data.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT s.StateName,s.StateNum, COUNT(s.StateNum) as [count]
FROM States AS s
INNER JOIN StateIncludeInClueReport as scr ON scr.statenum = s.StateNum
LEFT JOIN Staging_Policy sp ON CONVERT(TINYINT,SUBSTRING(sp.ProducerCode,1,2)) = s.StateNum
left JOIN (SELECT MIN(sip.QuoteId)AS QuoteId,sip.rmId FROM Staging_Policy sip GROUP BY sip.RMID) as sq ON sq.QuoteId = sp.QuoteID
INNER JOIN dbo.ResultMaster AS rm ON rm.rmID = sq.RMID
INNER JOIN dbo.CreditReport AS cr ON rm.rmID = cr.rmID AND cr.PolType = 'AUTO 3.0'
GROUP BY CONVERT(TINYINT,SUBSTRING(sp.ProducerCode,1,2)), s.StateName, s.StateNum
ORDER BY s.StateNum
```

But I'm still not seeing an records that don't appear in the rest of the data.

[I've created a sqlFiddle with the given scema and sample data.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31ee8/13)

The current output its:

```
STATENAME   STATENUM    COUNT
Kentucky    16          14
Ohio        34          4
```

The desired output would be:

```
STATENAME   STATENUM    COUNT
Arkansas    3           0
Georgia     10          0
Indiana     13          0
Kentucky    16          14
Missouri    24          0
Ohio        34          4
Tennessee   41          0
Texas       42          0
Virginia    45          0
```

I'm not really a SQL expert and this has really been giving me trouble. Would anyone have some insights into what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes to your query, including using `LEFT JOIN` on most of the joins:

```
SELECT s.StateName,
  s.StateNum,
  isNull(COUNT(cr.PolType), 0) as [count]
FROM States AS s
INNER JOIN StateIncludeInClueReport as scr 
  ON scr.statenum = s.StateNum
LEFT JOIN Staging_Policy sp 
  ON CONVERT(TINYINT,SUBSTRING(sp.ProducerCode,1,2)) = s.StateNum
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT MIN(sip.QuoteId)AS QuoteId, sip.rmId 
  FROM Staging_Policy sip GROUP BY sip.RMID
) as sq 
  ON sq.QuoteId = sp.QuoteID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ResultMaster AS rm 
  ON rm.rmID = sq.RMID
LEFT JOIN dbo.CreditReport AS cr 
  ON rm.rmID = cr.rmID
  AND cr.PolType = 'AUTO 3.0'
GROUP BY CONVERT(TINYINT,SUBSTRING(sp.ProducerCode,1,2)), s.StateName, s.StateNum
ORDER BY s.StateNum;
```

## See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31ee8/44)

Comment: That is amazing, I've been struggling for an entire day. If you could, would it be possible to explain what I was doing wrong?

Comment: @asawyer since you were using an `INNER JOIN` is was looking for records that were matching in all of the tables but we were trying to also return missing records so you need a `LEFT JOIN`.  Also on the `COUNT()` I switched to use `cr.PolType` instead of `s.StateNum` because that would always return at least `1` since the number exists from your first table.  So I changed it to `COUNT()` a field that could be missing.

Comment: @asawyer if you remove the `count()`, `GROUP BY` and `SELECT *` you can review the data that is being returned by both the `INNER` vs `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight into this.